# What is the easiest way for me to take a video of what I'm doing on a Linux desktop?

Tags: x11, video, desktop

Sort of like the Windows counterpart of CamStudio.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have a look at [RecordMyDesktop](http://recordmydesktop.sourceforge.net/about.php) or [Freeeseer](https://github.com/fosslc/freeseer/wiki).

Answer (score 4):

What about [recordmydesktop](http://recordmydesktop.sourceforge.net/downloads.php)?
With gui front end GtkRecordMyDesktop.

**NOTE**: Before down votes note that this was the first answer.